# cannot read property 'init' of undefined in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-digits

I am creating a web app using angularjs, and I need to add twitter Digits in my web app.

I insert `angular-digits.js` file:

I include this file in HTML `<head>` section:

```
<script src="js/angular-digits.js"></script>
```

call this file in `app.js` file:

```
angular.module("sampleApp", ["firebase","atticoos.digits","ngRoute"]);
```

It's working with Firefox browser.

but in Chrome browser display

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined "
```

Comment: Can you reproduce in a jsfiddle?

Comment: I think you are adding a js file in more than one place. please check this.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem today and comes out we both forgot to include this script:
https://cdn.digits.com/1/sdk.js without which Digits can't be set up properly!

Hope that helps